# Option to specify base server url for can.Model?

Tags: canjs, canjs-model

Is there a way to specify the base url for can.Model?

I see the server path being hard coded this way:

```
Wine = can.Model({
    findAll : 'GET //localhost/Cellar-CanJS-Bootstrapped/api/wines',
    findOne : 'GET //localhost/Cellar-CanJS-Bootstrapped/api/wines/{id}',
    create  : 'POST //localhost/Cellar-CanJS-Bootstrapped/api/wines',
    update  : 'PUT //localhost/Cellar-CanJS-Bootstrapped/api/wines/{id}',
    destroy : 'DELETE //localhost/Cellar-CanJS-Bootstrapped/api/wines/{id}'
},{
})
```

What I'm looking for is a way specify the base url for the Model so that I can continue to configure my can.Model is the standard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately setting a model base URL is not a built in feature yet but planned for the next minor release. This is how I usually do it at the moment:

```
function getUrl(url, method) {
    method = method || 'GET';
    return method + ' ' + BASE_URL + '/' + url;
}

Wine = can.Model({
    findAll : getUrl('api/wines');
    findOne : getUrl('api/wines/{id}'),
    create  : getUrl('api/wines', 'POST'),
    update  : getUrl('wines/{id}', 'PUT'),
    destroy : getUrl('api/wines/{id}', 'DELETE')
},{
});
```

`getUrl` can be a Model static method or located in a better spot (e.g. application bootstrap) as well.

Comment: Thanks Daff -- that's how I am doing it at the moment too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resource` property:

```
Wine = can.Model.extend({
    resource : "//localhost/Cellar-CanJS-Bootstrapped/api/wines",
},{});
```

Docs: http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.resource.html